# RF24 code not working:

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+, code-review

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSHJ-RLbNJk) and used his [transmitter code](https://github.com/RalphBacon/nRF24L01-transceiver/blob/master/nRF24L01_Test_Node_1/nRF24L01_Test_Node_1.ino) and [receiver code](https://github.com/RalphBacon/nRF24L01-transceiver/blob/master/nRF24L01_Test_Node_0/nRF24L01_Test_Node_0.ino). However, it's not working. There's no response from the receiver.

The transmitter stuck at the loop:

```
if (!radio.write( &data, sizeof(unsigned char) )) {
Serial.println("No acknowledgement of transmission - receiving radio device connected?"); 
}
```

and the receiver never received anything and only printed:

```
  Serial.println("THIS IS THE RECEIVER CODE - YOU NEED THE OTHER ARDUINO TO TRANSMIT");
```

I've been stuck here for hours. I checked the hardware, there's no issue there. I also tried to adjust the code couple of times, and it looked decent but not helping. Could you help me to check what went wrong with the code please?

Comment: Try moving the transmitter and receiver further apart.

Comment: Check your wiring thrice, 99% of issues are there. Make sure the 3.3V bus is decoupled with at least 10mF of capacitance, noise on the 3.3V bus is an enormous no-no for nRF24L01+.

Comment: After that is done, find the RF24 examples from Arduino IDE, upload those to your boards with the right configuration and see if those work - it's a battle-tested piece of code.

Comment: @Avamander I saw your post in Arduino forum. However, it did not work for me. I went the expansive way. I tried the multiple noise filter, but it did not help. Eventually I got a special adapter with onboard regulator, it still didn't work. Turns out, it has to do with the communication device itself. The one I got had an antenna that strength singal the distance and penetration. But somehow it made the device very unreliable, possibly because it's receiving single within a mile. Once I switched to a weaker chip, it worked out immediately and the data was guaranteed.  Though less sensitive.

Comment: Even the modules with PA+LNA should work fine closer-range or in noisy environments. The most usual problem is that the power usage is underestimated, instead of the usual 14mA during transmission it could take hundreds, and that is above what onboard and could be above what small 3.3V regulators can provide. A few millifarads attached between GND and 3.3V should already improve reliability if it's the power that's the issue.

Comment: @Avamander There's nothing wrong with power. The single is very clean and I got maximum output of over 10W. I'm more and more sure it's the single receiving of that range-extended model. It's perpetuation ability was too good.  Does nRF24 library has any built in code to filter the single noise?(from the environment) I think the device is boosting every single received from the entire building. So it was not affected by the power supply, but the fact that the environment was so noise troubled actual single received.

Comment: @Avamander With weaker cheap, it's only able to receive the strongest single above certain threshold, thus a better communication quality and shorter range. i.e. it does not have the powerful LNA module.

Comment: `Does nRF24 library has any built in code to filter the single noise?` No, that can't be done.

Comment: `The single is very clean and I got maximum output of over 10W.` Are you within legal limits? The 2.4GHz band is for everyone to use.

Comment: @Avamander I set it to be min after the test.  and the channel I googled and used the channel that's not used by states providers

Comment: `It's perpetuation ability was too good. [...] think the device is boosting every single received from the entire building.` A nearby source will still most certainly overpower any far away noise source, receiving should work. The fact that a weaker module works still indicates a power supply issue rather than noise issue. However it's also possible that you have stumbled upon a counterfeit nRF24L01+, by any chance is it under a blob of epoxy?